# Bootstrap 4 Sidebar dropdown aria expanded background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a sidebar which contains a drop-down. And if the dropdown is open. I want the `<li class="nav-item nav-item-sidebar">` (Which is at the top of the whole dropdown) to have a certain CSS style. Which is

```
border-left: 3px solid #1ABB9C;
padding: 8px 8px 8px 5px;
background-color: #222732;
```

How can I achieve that?

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-sidebar">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fal fa-thumbs-up fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
            <span class="sidebar-link">Dropdown</span>
            <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow rotate-effect"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#Bier1" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
                    <i class="fal fa-copy fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
                    <span class="sidebar-link">Files</span>
                    <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#Bier2" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
                    <i class="fal fa-comments fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
                    <span class="sidebar-link">Comments</span>
                    <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#Bier3" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
                    <i class="fal fa-image fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
                    <span class="sidebar-link">Pictures</span>
                    <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I guess it has something to do with `a[aria-expanded="true"]` but I'm not sure.

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here when the dropdown is called, collapse class will change the colour of the items. And btnBackground is called from a jquery, and it will apply the css. Try this out.

In the dropdown items, the effect is happening after loading the default css, but you can change it when the dropdown is loaded, this is to show how the colour changes from default to the css you added.

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("btnBackground");
});
```

```css
.btnBackground {
  border-left: 3px solid #1ABB9C;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 5px;
  background-color: #222732;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<li class="nav-item nav-item-sidebar dropdown-toggle">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fal fa-thumbs-up fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
    <span class="sidebar-link">Dropdown</span>
    <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow rotate-effect"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#Bier1" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
        <i class="fal fa-copy fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-link">Files</span>
        <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#Bier2" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
        <i class="fal fa-comments fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-link">Comments</span>
        <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#Bier3" class="nav-link sidebar-dropdown-nav-link">
        <i class="fal fa-image fa-lg sidebar-icon"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-link">Pictures</span>
        <span class="fal fa-angle-right fa-lg sidebar-arrow"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're giving the `<a>` tag the class btnBackground while the `<li>` tag above the `<a>` tag needs to have the styles. Can you alter it to that? Or is that impossible to do?

Comment: Check the edited answer, You can still get the colour change, but there are few changes happening, so i removed the .collapse from the styling. Now there is a small issue in the css as you can see

Answer (score 0):

You cant access parent elements with css, as far as I know.
But here you have a pure css solution to archive you goal.

```
.nav-item.nav-item-sidebar a[aria-expanded="true"], 
.nav-item.nav-item-sidebar a[aria-expanded="true"] + ul {
    border-left: 3px solid #1ABB9C;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 5px; 
    background-color: #222732;
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amsq2dys/)